# Does $A^2 \geq B^2 > 0$ imply $ACA \geq BCB$ for square positive definite matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, positive-definite

Assume we have two $n \times n$ real nondegenerate matrices $ A^2 $ and $B^2$, such that
$$
A^2 \geq B^2 > 0,
$$
where "$\geq$" means positive semidefinite (Loewner) ordering. Does the following inequality holds for any real matrix $C$ 
$$
ACA \geq BCB \ ?
$$
If not, under which conditions on $C$ (or additional conditions on $A$ and $B$) does it holds?

I would appreciate any ideas, suggestions, counterexamples.
Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I don't know if there are any nice (i.e. not-too-strong) conditions for the inequality to hold, but I'm sure that it doesn't always hold, even when $C$ is positive definite. Counterexample:
\begin{align}
A&=A^2=I,\\
B&=B^2=\frac12\pmatrix{1&1\\ 1&1},\\
C&=\operatorname{diag}(1,4).
\end{align}
In this case, we have $A^2\ge B^2\ge 0$ but $ACA-BCB=\frac14\pmatrix{-1&-5\\ -5&11}$ is indefinite. While $B$ is not positive definite here, by continuity, we can obtain a valid counterexample by adding a small positive multiple of $I$ to both $A$ and $B$.

**Edit.**

1. Note that if $ACA\ge BCB$ for *all* real symmetric $C$, we must have $A=B$ because $AIA\ge BIB$ and $A(-I)A\ge B(-I)B$ imply that $A^2=B^2$.
2. It isn't quite meaningful to consider $ACA\ge BCB$ for *all* $C\ge0$ either. In particular, if $A(vv^\ast)A\ge B(vv^\ast)B$ for every vector $v$, then $Bv$ must be equal to $\lambda_v Av$ for some $0\le\lambda_v\le1$. Therefore, by linearity, $B=\lambda A$ for some $0\le\lambda\le1$.
3. It is interesting to ask, however, if $A\ge B>0$ and $A^2\ge B^2$, what class of $C$ (under perhaps some additional conditions on $A$ and $B$) would satisfy the inequality $ACA\ge BCB$.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

In [Theorem 2.6a, 1] it is proven using Fuglede-Putnam that

> **Proposition.** For $I \geq A, B \geq 0$ we have $\sqrt{A} B \sqrt{A} \leq B$ if and only if $AB = BA$.

(The matrix $\sqrt{A} B \sqrt{A}$ models the sequential measurement of first $A$ andthen $B$ in quantum mechanics and its properties are studied by various authors.  By them it is called the "sequential product").

As a corollary we can partially answer your question:

> **Corollary.**  Suppose $I \geq A,B \geq 0$ with $A^2 \geq B^2$.  If for all real $C$, we have $ACA \geq BCB$, then $AB=BA$.

**Proof.** Consider $C:=A$. By assumption $A \geq A^2 \geq BAB=\sqrt{B^2}A\sqrt{B^2}$ and so $B^2$ commutes with $A$.  But then also~$B$ commutes with $A$. **QED**

[1] Sequential quantum measurements by Gudder and Nagy

Comment: The proposition does not sound right. When $B>0$, the inequality $\sqrt{A}B\sqrt{A}\le B$ is always satisfied by any sufficiently small $A$.

Comment: @user1551 Could you give an example?

Comment: Let $B$ and $C$ be two non-commuting positive definite matrices and let $A=\frac{\lambda_\min(B)}{\lambda_\max(B)\lambda_\max(C)}C$. Then $\lambda_\max(A)= \frac{\lambda_\min(B)}{\lambda_\max(B)}\le1$ and $\lambda_\max(\sqrt{A}\sqrt{B}\sqrt{A})\le\|A\|\|B\|=\lambda_\min(B)$. Therefore $A\le I$ and $\sqrt{A}B\sqrt{A}\le B$. However, since $BC\ne CB$, we have $AB\ne BA$.

Comment: Let $B=\left(\begin{array}{cc}1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0\end{array}\right)$ be the projection on $(1,0)$ and $C=\frac{1}{2}\left(\begin{array}{cc} 1&1\\1&1 \end{array}\right)$ be the projection on $(1,1)$. Then the minimal eigenvalue of $B$ is $0$ so with your definition $A=0$.  So $AB=BA$ and your counterexample can't hold as is.  If there is a counter-example, you could just give three matrices concretely.

Comment: In my counterexample $B,C$ and hence $A$ are positive definite. Your $B$ isn't.

Comment: If you want a concrete counterexample, let $A=\frac14\pmatrix{1&1\\ 1&1}$ and $B=\pmatrix{1\\ &1/2}$. Then $B-\sqrt{A}B\sqrt{A}=\frac{1}{16}\pmatrix{13&-3\\ -3&5}\ge0$ but $AB\ne BA$.

Comment: You are right about my previous objection to your previous counterexample — I read positive semidefinite instead of positive definite.

Your last counterexample does not invalidate my corollary as $A^2 \leq B^2$ whereas my corollary assumes $B^2 \leq A^2$.

Comment: I am not talking about the statement in the corollary in your answer. I am talking about the first proposition in your answer. The "only if" part of the proposition is wrong, as shown by the counterexample given in my previous comment. As you apparently have used the "only if" part of the proposition to prove your corollary, your proof is invalid.

Comment: By the way, the condition in the mentioned paper is $\sqrt{A}B\sqrt{A}\ge B$, but you have reversed the direction of the inequality in your proposition.

Answer (score -2):

[Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1789462/is-the-loewner-ordering-maintained-after-multiplication-with-positive-definite-m) I posted a related question. My (preliminary) conclusion to this question might be a valuable idea/suggestion to your answer: 
I strongly assume (!) when your matrices commute (i.e. $(AB)^T AB = AB (AB)^T$) then $ACA \geq BCB$. This could be the case when $A$, $B$, and $C$ are diagonal matrices (and of course in the trivial cases of $C$ or $A$ and $B$ being multiples of $I$).